# Javascript - loop 3 functions with delay in between each function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please - no jQuery.

Function 1 causes an image to appear (CSS3 animation).

Function 2 then slides up a caption on the bottom of this slide (CSS3 animation).

Function 3 then slides down the caption (CSS3 animation).

Then the process needs to be repeated.

**My question: how to put these functions in a continuous loop with a delay in between every function.**

HTML code

```
<div id="slider">

        <!-- Sildes 
             img_noshow means opacity:0;display:none;
             img_show means opacity:1;
             an_movein means a fade in effect CSS3
        -->
        <img id="img_1" class='img_show' src="/images/c1.jpg" style='width:960px;'/>
        <img id="img_2" class='img_noshow' src="/images/c2.jpg" style='width:960px;'/>
        <img id="img_3" class='img_noshow' src="/images/c3.jpg" style='width:960px;'/>
        <img id="img_4" class='img_noshow' src="/images/c4.jpg" style='width:960px;'/>
        <div id="slider_caption">
        <p id="slider_p1" class="an_slideup"><a href="#one">This is the text going with the slide 1.</a></p>
        <p id="slider_p2" class="img_noshow"><a href="#one">This is the text going with the slide 2.</a></p>
        <p id="slider_p3" class="img_noshow"><a href="#one">This is the text going with the slide 3.</a></p>
        <p id="slider_p4" class="img_noshow"><a href="#one">This is the text going with the slide 4.</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT code

```
slide = 1;//global
function nextMove(){
  slide++;
  if(slide > 4){
    slide = 1;
  }
  //img_noshow means opacity:0;display:none;
  //img_show means opacity:1;
  //an_movein means a fade in effect
  for(i=1;i<5;i++){

    document.getElementById('slider_p'+i).className = 'img_noshow';
    if(i != slide){
      document.getElementById('img_'+i).className = 'img_noshow';
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('img_'+i).className = 'an_movein';
    }
  }
}


function nextMove2(){
  document.getElementById('slider_p'+slide).className = 'an_slideup';
}

function nextMove3(){
  document.getElementById('slider_p'+slide).className = 'an_slidedown';
}
```

Comment: Pls. No "text" words.  Type the full word.

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: @flukyspore: He's talking about writing "pls" instead of "please". It's considered good netiquette to make an effort when you write a question so that it's easy to read. Using txtspk makes it look like you are more concerned about how long it takes to write the question than to make it a pleasant read. However, a single txtspk word in a question is hardly worth commenting, that would just be to inform you of that piece of netiquette for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `setTimeout` method at the end of each function to start the next after a delay:

```
function nextMove(){
  //...all dat code
  window.setTimeout(nextMove2, 500);
}

function nextMove2(){
  document.getElementById('slider_p'+slide).className = 'an_slideup';
  window.setTimeout(nextMove3, 500);
}

function nextMove3(){
  document.getElementById('slider_p'+slide).className = 'an_slidedown';
  window.setTimeout(nextMove, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most literal example:

```
setInterval(function() {
  nextMove();
  setTimeout(function() {
    nextMove2();
    setTimeout(nextMove3, 5000)
  }, 5000);
}, 15000);
```

So every 15 seconds start the loop. Execute the first function, wait 5 seconds, execute the 2nd, wait 5 seconds, and execute the third (so after that, you wait ~5 seconds for the first again).

Comment: setInterval is crashing the browser.Ideal one is setInterval